# Mismatch between firebase realtime cli donwloaded bytes and firebase console downloaded bytes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a chat app in android using android Firebase Realtime Database, when I decided to check the downloaded data then it was showing a lot of downloaded data in Android app info segment but I  thought maybe here I am shown some extra data maybe for user images or anything else[image].

So I just jumped to the Firebase console and concluded that I downloaded 400 kb of data in a single instance of opening the app and on the phone it was around 600kb.

So to see what's going wrong I downloaded Firebase Cli and just saw that I am downloading atmost 200 kb of data only.

Where is that extra 200 kb coming from, SSL overheads cant be this much, it's just the double.

As Firebase documentation says:-
**SSL encryption overhead: There is a cost associated with the SSL encryption overhead necessary for secure connections. On average, this cost is approximately 3.5KB for the initial handshake, and approximately 40B for TLS record headers on each outgoing message.**

So whenever I attach a new listener to a location is that considered a new connection, if not what does a new connection means in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on [profiling the performance of the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) explicitly says:

> Don't use the profiler tool to estimate bandwidth cost. The profiler tool is intended to give you an overall picture of your database's performance, to help you monitor operations and troubleshoot issues, not to estimate billing. It doesn't account for network traffic, it only records an estimate of the application data sent in responses.
>
> The following are some common examples of network traffic billed by Firebase that aren't covered in your database profile:
>
> - Protocol overhead: Some additional traffic between the server and clients is necessary to establish and maintain a session. Depending on the underlying protocol, this traffic might include: Firebase Realtime Database's realtime protocol overhead, WebSocket overhead, and HTTP header overhead. Each time a connection is established, this overhead, combined with any SSL encryption overhead, contributes to the connection costs. Although this is typically not a large amount of bandwidth, it can be substantial if your payloads are tiny or you make frequent, short connections.
> - SSL encryption overhead: There is a cost associated with the SSL encryption overhead necessary for secure connections. On average, this cost is approximately 3.5KB for the initial handshake, and approximately 40B for TLS record headers on each outgoing message. For most apps, this is a small percentage of your bill. However, this could become a large percentage if your specific case requires a lot of SSL handshakes. For example, devices that don't support TLS session tickets might require large numbers of SSL connection handshakes.
>
> Read more about understanding and estimating your bill.

So apparently SSL and protocol overhead **are** that much.

If you want to get a better idea of the actual traffic, you might want to look at the actual wire traffic with a packet sniffer.

Comment: If that is the case then it won't be efficient for a chat app I think

Comment: Is there any way to lower down the overheads? Using packet sniffer in my android device I can only see 6 kb of data from this app for SSL overheads

Comment: There's more than just SSL overhead. As the documentation says, there's also some over overhead. The web socket frame wrappers for example, the wire protocol that Firebase uses on top of that, and HTTP headers. None of these are under your control though.